# Understanding const references and non-const references to iterators in C++. Why can't I use a non-const reference to iterator in the print function?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

**Can someone explain to me the difference between `const iterator` reference and `non-const iterator` reference in C++ please?
Why can't I use a `non-const iterator` reference in the `print` function?**

---

The following code does not compile.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> ostream & print(T & start, T & end) {
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
        cout << *start << " ";
    }
    return cout;
}

int main() {
    int tab[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    deque<int> d1(tab, tab + 10);
    deque<int> d2;
    deque<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = d1.begin(); it != d1.end(); ++it) {
        d2.push_back(d1[d1.end() - it - 1]); //LINE I
    }
    print(d2.rbegin(), d2.rend()) << endl; //LINE II
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is somewhat cryptic to me.

```
hello.cpp:21:33: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*> >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::deque<int>::reverse_iterator {aka std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*> >}’
     print(d2.rbegin(), d2.rend()) << endl; //LINE II
                                 ^
hello.cpp:6:32: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘std::ostream& print(T&, T&) [with T = std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*> >; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
 template<typename T> ostream & print(T & start, T & end) {
```

---

I managed to change the code (based on another code example) to make it work.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> ostream & print(const T & start, const T & end) {
    T tmp = start;
    for (; tmp != end; ++tmp) {
        cout << *tmp << " ";
    }
    return cout;
}

int main() {
    int tab[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    deque<int> d1(tab, tab + 10);
    deque<int> d2;
    deque<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = d1.begin(); it != d1.end(); ++it) {
        d2.push_back(d1[d1.end() - it - 1]); //LINE I
    }
    print(d2.rbegin(), d2.rend()) << endl; //LINE II
    return 0;
}
```

And I get a result.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

I think the differences are the declaration of `const iterator` reference and `non-const iterator` reference. But I don't understand why. I checked [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and I tried to review my course, but I am not successful in gaining understanding.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with const and non-const iterators. In this line:

```
print(d2.rbegin(), d2.rend()) << endl;
```

`rbegin()` and `rend()` return temporaries of type `reverse_iterator`. `print()`, on the other hand, takes lvalue references:

```
template<typename T> ostream & print(T & start, T & end);
```

You cannot take an lvalue reference to a temporary, so the code can't compile. The error says exactly that - you're trying to initialize a non-const reference with a temporary:

> hello.cpp:21:33: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::reverse_iterator >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::deque::reverse_iterator {aka std::reverse_iterator >}’

You *can* initialize a *const* reference with a temporary, which is why your fix works. But really, you don't need to take references at all. Just write your `print()` to take its iterators by value:

```
template<typename T>
ostream & print(T start, T end) {
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
        cout << *start << " ";
    }
    return cout;
}
```

The entire standard library suite of algorithms does it this way. Do as the standard library do.

Comment: Thank you @Barry. I got this code from the course. Can you think of a reason why one would use references (considering that the library passes iterators by value)?

Comment: @Elyasin There's probably a use-case, but it's certainly atypical. You'd have to come up with a compelling reason to use references. Passing by-value should be your default.

Comment: @Elyasin the course instructor probably misunderstood iterators

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are so right. I continue with the course and it seems that the examples all are suffering *bugs*. Now I learned that I have to be able to distinguish between the older C++ and C++11 (which is not part of the curriculum). It's so time consuming :-(